# Add header property in a Rest call in C#

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I have a Rest call which looks like this:

```
[OperationContract]
[XmlSerializerFormat]
[WebGet(
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
    UriTemplate = "someplace/{something}")]
RestApiResponse GetData(string something);
```

The client call this method like this:

```
RestApiResponse Channel.GetData(something);
```

A Java server is handling this call in the other side.

Now I want to add version number of client to each call to server. For that purpose I want to add it to the Rest header, so it will be sent in every call.

How can I add a version property to the header of each call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple

```
WebOperationContext webOperationContext = WebOperationContext.Current;
if (webOperationContext != null)
{
    webOperationContext.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("X-Version", "1");
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Did the job perfectly and elegantly.